# Highlight first paragraph of plaintext

Tags: javascript, css

My application saves plaintext with **line-breaks**, e.g.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Suspendisse porttitor mauris cursus neque vehicula scelerisque. 

Proin eget euismod purus
```

When displaying this data, I ensure the line-breaks are preserved using **css**:

```
//  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. 
// Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
white-space: pre-line;
```

**Is it possible to highlight the first paragraph with css, i.e. all text before the first line-break?**

I am thinking similar to `p:first-of-type { font-weight: bold };`... only that there are no p-elements here. Is this possible?

Comment: There is a `:first-line` selector... but if the first paragraph is long and wraps it won't work. Is there a `<br>` tag in the markup? You could use js to select the first text node that way.

Comment: There are no `<br>` tags in the plaintext. For context, the data is is retrieved from Google Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I have tried using the `:first-line` selector. However this only highlights the actual first line, which is not enough if the first paragraph is longer and wraps.

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this with css unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the problem further, one possible solution is to add `<p>` tags to the plaintext manually, using **JS/TS** to detect the line-breaks:

```
// convert plaintext-lines to paragraph-elements
convertPlaintextToParagraphs( text: string ) {

    // convert plaintext to array
    // by using line-breaks as element-separators
    let lines: string[] = text.split('\n');

    // add <p> tags to each array-element
    let textWithParagraphs: string = ""; 
    lines.forEach( paragraph => {
         textWithParagraphs += "<p>" + paragraph + "</p>";
    });

    // return result
    return textWithParagraphs;
}
```

This then allows using **CSS** to highlight the first `<p>`:

```
p:first-of-type {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

*PS: Alternative, neater, more concise, etc answers are appreciated!*

Comment: if you're accepting js answers now then add the js tag to the question.

Comment: Added the JavaScript tag to the question!